# Special case of the Stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

I have the following problem:
Let $\phi$ be a 2-form in $\mathbb{R}^3/{0}$ with $$\phi=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(xdy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx\wedge dy)$$
Calculatate $\int_{S^2}\phi$ with the Stokes theorem.

Here I have the problem that $\phi$ is not defined for $(0,0,0)$.
Can someone explain how to use the theorem on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is, formally, $d\phi$?

Comment: So $d\phi$ should be $0$ I guess

Comment: So what do you get by applying Stokes' theorem, disregarding the singularity of $\phi$ (or $d\phi$) at the origin?

Comment: So Stokes says: $$\int_{S^2}d\phi=\int_{\partial S^2}\phi$$
How can I apply this? I should calculate $\int_{S^2}\phi$. How do I use the $d\phi$ here?

Comment: Please be careful: $S^2$ is the boundary of the unit ball $U$, hence $$\int_{\partial U} \phi = \int_{U} d\phi = 0$$

Comment: Oh I thought $S^2$ would be the complete sphere. My mistake.
Ok now $\int_Ud\phi$ is 0. But until now we disregarded the singularity.

Comment: And there is no issue in doing that, since the singularity of $\phi$ does not lie on $S^2$ and the integral $\int_U d\phi $ stays the same if we change the value of $d\phi$ at the origin only.

Comment: I don’t believe the singularity can be disregarded so carelessly. Consider the form $d\theta = \frac{x dy-y dx }{x^2+y^2}$ and integrate over $S^1$.

Comment: The singularity should not be discarded, since $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq U\setminus \mathrm 0$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on the unit sphere, the denominator of $\phi$ is 1. The numerator of $\phi$ is recognizable as the 2-dimensional volume form on the sphere, so the integral is simply the surface area of the sphere, $4\pi$. Note that despite the fact that $\phi$ is closed on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\} $, the singularity within the unit ball prevents us from applying Stokes’ theorem.